# assign value of a property of "clearsky" from "object" to weather so to pass through src in the image tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

The expected result is to first find weather string from array of object "objects" and then set value of "weather" variable equal to value of of clearsky value(i.e. link).

```
let weather = "clearsky";

  const objects = [
    { "clearsky": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/11d@2x.png" },
    { "cloudy": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/19d@2x.png" },
    { "rainny": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" },
    { "sunny": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/12d@2x.png" },
  ];

  //expected result is to first find weather string from array of object "objects" and then set value of weather equal to value of 
  weather = {
    /* <img src={weather} alt=""/> */
  };
```

Comment: Hi MrDevilHunter, I don't believe you've included a question in your description :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to write some sort of function that displays your image corresponding to the right value (weather type) in your objects array.

I added these `<img>` tags (for displaying in your html).

```html
<img id="img-clearsky">
<img id="img-rainy">
```

I changed the structure of your objects array a bit so that property values can be accessed in a simple way. I made a function that loops through your array and if it finds a match for your objects `type`, it uses the corresponding `imgurl` to load as `src` of the element with given `id`.

```js
const objects = [{
    "type": "clearsky",
    "imgurl": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/11d@2x.png"
  },
  {
    "type": "rainy",
    "imgurl": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png"
  }
];

function displayImage(weatherType, elemid) {
  const imgelem = document.getElementById(elemid); // Get img element by id.
  // If element with given id exists.
  if (imgelem !== null) {
    // Loop through objects.
    for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
      // Check if there is a match.
      if (objects[i].type === weatherType) {
        imgelem.src = objects[i].imgurl; // Fill up <img src>  with corresponding url.
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log(`No img with id: ${elemid} found.`);
  }
}

// Call display with type and id.
displayImage('clearsky', 'img-clearsky');
displayImage('rainy', 'img-rainy');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this, but I would wrap this logic with a function - especially if you plan on splitting this into several constants.

```js
const WeatherTypeImage = (weatherType = 'clearsky') => 
  Object.assign(document.createElement('img'), {
    src: {
      "clearsky": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/11d@2x.png",
      "cloudy": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/19d@2x.png",
      "rainny": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png",
      "sunny": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/12d@2x.png",
    }[weatherType],
    alt: '',
  })

document.querySelector('.js-container').appendChild(
  WeatherTypeImage()
)
```

```html
<div class="js-container"></div>
```

Or, if you would prefer to have an HTML string template:

```js
const WeatherTypeImage = (weatherType = 'clearsky') => {
  const src = {
    "clearsky": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/11d@2x.png",
    "cloudy": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/19d@2x.png",
    "rainny": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png",
    "sunny": "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/12d@2x.png",
  }[weatherType]

  return Object.assign(document.createElement('template'), {
    innerHTML: `<img src="${src}" alt="">`
  }).content
}

document.querySelector('.js-container').appendChild(
  WeatherTypeImage()
)
```

```html
<div class="js-container"></div>
```